# which database is better for my case? sql? nosql? newsql?

Tags: python, sql, nosql

right now i have project which is about gathering information about country wide real estate active dealers and etc. the goal is to create an information system for real estate activists, the data gathering at the first stage would be with users input and at next stages we will use robots. at the end we will have an complete database to make advanced reports, even we have ideas about using AI technologies. we want to use python and Django, our big challenge in choosing right database management software are these issues: 1- we may change or add new fields to classes, like id, postal code, etc. 2- our goal is using this database to analyze and create advanced reports (maybe with machine learning and AI) can you help me with the right answer? thank you.

Comment: I think it's pretty much a matter of taste; a goal this broad should be achievable with any sufficiently mature DBMS. The stuff about how you will be LEFT BEHIND from the AGILE CLOUD DISRUPTION OF BUSINESS INTELLIGENCE if you don't use NoSQL is just marketing hype.

Comment: You have not provided enough information about specific needs to make a reasonable suggestion. You need to describe more details about your data, the types, the volume, the nature of your app(s) and users. Will this involve geo information, in which case Postgres and PostGIS is the obvious solution?

Comment: yes, we will have peoples information, firms information. (both together would be about 3 millions.) we will have Geo information and it could become a key element for features AI analyzes. we will have documents like videos and pics and ... . we will have spider engines to gather information, we will have analyzes about relations and graph results ... .

Comment: @shakiba Edit your Question to provide additional info rather than post as comments. Don't make the reader trawl through comments to decipher your question.

Answer (score 1):

## PostGIS

[image]

Apparently you say you need geographic/geospatial information features. In that case, your choice is either:

- Pay large fees to a commercial company like Oracle, or
- Use the free-of-cost open-source [*PostGIS*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostGIS) system built on [*Postgres*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL), the world's most advanced open-source database.